# std::move() - how is it advantageous for native data types?

Tags: c++

Does `std::move()` have any impact on native types or native pointers? If not, then for vectors, how does it internally nullify temporary built-in types, even if there is no custom move constructor?

Comment: "*how for vectors it internally nullifies temporary built-in types object*" Can you explain what you mean here?

Comment: How vector internally implements move constructor?

Comment: It doesn't involve temporaries of any kind.

Comment: @sumitkumar your compiler's vector implementation is freely open for you to look at, but in a nutshell a vector contains a pointer to an array. The vector's move constructor simply moves that pointer from the source vector to the new vector, and then nulls the pointer in the source vector.

Comment: Also note that `std::move` is just a cast and doesn't itself do anything

Answer (score 1):

*Does std::move() have any impact on native types or native pointers?*

---

No, for native types or native pointers they are just a copy, you can verify it by seeing the [disassembly](https://godbolt.org/z/fre8rz46o), for integer types or pointers, the optimized disassembly is all one instruction, they can't be faster than a copy.

*Then for vectors, how does it internally nullify temporary built-in types*

---

Firstly, `std::move` is just cast, it doesn't move anything. The [implenmentation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/move.h#L101) for libstdc++ :

```cpp
  template<typename _Tp>
    _GLIBCXX_NODISCARD
    constexpr typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&
    move(_Tp&& __t) noexcept
    { return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&>(__t); }
```

Then for the implementation of `std::vector`, it's somewhat like this, there are 3 data members, all of them are pointers. `_M_start` pointer to the begin address of user data, `_M_finish` pointer the end address of user data.

```cpp
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
class Vector {
      typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::template
    rebind<_Tp>::other _Tp_alloc_type;
      typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Tp_alloc_type>::pointer
        pointer;
    pointer _M_start;
    pointer _M_finish;
    pointer _M_end_of_storage;
};
```

And for the `move constructor`, it will like this:

```cpp
    Vector (Vector && __x) noexcept
    : _M_start(__x._M_start), _M_finish(__x._M_finish),
      _M_end_of_storage(__x._M_end_of_storage)
    { __x._M_start = __x._M_finish = __x._M_end_of_storage = pointer(); }
```

Only pointer assignment happens here, so it's much faster than the pre-c++11 version, at the time we can only copy all the elements from the source vector and destroy the old vector, you can confirm by checking the [old version](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-4.0/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L233) of libstdc++

```
      vector(const vector& __x)
      :
      {
          this->_M_finish =
              std::__uninitialized_copy_a(__x.begin(), __x.end(),
                      this->._M_start,
                      this->get_allocator());
      }
```

For other STL containers like `deque`, `map`, they are all similar to `vector`.

So when will be `std::move` useful? When your class data member allocated heap memory or use STL containers. Or in an indirect way：the data member or base class benefits from `move constructor` or `move assignment operator`, then your class would benefit from it.

To read more about move constructors, and move assignment operators:
[Rule-of-Three becomes Rule-of-Five with C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)